# Is there any way to get algorithm of any Encrypted String?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, encryption, cryptography

File command shows that the file is of any type of ELF, Text, Ascii, source code. Is any there any command or tool to identify the possible encryption algorithm for a given String? or to find possible algorithms?

Comment: Is the content actually encrypted?

Comment: Yeah I’ve encrypted text and key but I don’t know the algorithm so I cannot decrypt it

Comment: Did you do it on the same machine? If yes: You could just look in the bash history (if you have it enabled) and find the command you used to encrypt it (if you did it recently - if not, it may no longer be in the history): `cat ~/.bash_history | grep filename`

Comment: Nope I just have file

Comment: Reverse engineering (finding the encryption command) probably is your best shot. If you know the passphrase you can check for available encryptions on your machine and try all of them and manually identify the right one. There might be a tool that can guess the encryption method, [also see this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3989/167811).

Comment: thank you @rudib